# Woocommerce CSS hovered product that overflowes over product below

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, overflow, css-position

I'm confused. I have products in grid displayed as `<li>` and need to show them taller on hover with overflowing over element below:

I set the height of `<li>` to only `366px` and `overflow: hidden;`, and on hover on `<li>` is `height: auto;` and `overflow: initial;`.

It works good, but:

[image]

On right side is a hovered `<li>` product. Last div and button are default hidden by setting smaller height and overflow hidden, and visible on hover. Highlighted gutter between products should be not visible.

`position: relative;` to parent element `<ul>` and `position: absolute;` on `<li>` is not working, because product don't stay on his place.

My code:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  padding: 0 15px;
  transition: 
  color .15s ease-in-out,
  background-color .15s ease-in-out,
  border-color .15s ease-in-out,
  box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none outside;

  //cut off last div and button from description
  height: 366px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.first {
  clear: both;
}

// hover state
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, .75);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(166, 166, 166, .75);
  height: auto;
  overflow: initial;
}
```

I need to produce hovered product that overflowes over product below without creating a gutter between them :

[image: graphic template]

I will provide link to the website via email. Can someone help? 
Still not resolved.

Comment: Try adding some scaling to the hover. Something like the below - adjust the value to your desired level of scale.  

transform: scale(1.5);

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. It's not working

Comment: @Juraj please provide the link of your site. so that we can check and solve your issue

Comment: I cannot provide link while website is in development...

Comment: Ok, I will provide link to website via email. Can You send me your email address please? Thanks.